# How to scale an application with tomcat and stateless j2ee architecture with spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-ee, scalability

supposing three machines that will receive the same S.O configured with the application, the database will be mongoDB with shared service (easy to configure and is not the main question here). But knowing the application to deploy (.war) is a stateless app so i can run it as "plug and play" way, my doubts are:

1) How to create a linux image of a virtual machine so i can easy install the same enviroment in the three differente machines?

2) How i can configure tomcat to be scalable? how they will distribute the request along the supposed cluster in the network?

3) There's some discussion group to this kind of topic (j2ee scalability)? i don't feel confortably putting so many novice questions here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe you want to take a look on Vagrant (which gives you the oppertunity to create and configure virtual machines, page: https://www.vagrantup.com/) if you want to define a virtual machine.
   With Chef / Puppet you can 'decorate' your virtual machines, i.e. define a directory structure or include specific applications and/or databases (page: https://www.getchef.com/chef/ and http://puppetlabs.com/ for puppet).
2. Tomcat has a cluster feature which can replicate session data (and more) between the cluster nodes (checkout http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html for more information).